# How to enable multiple login tries in asp.net forms authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a MVC project with forms authentication.

Basically it works fine:
The user wants to access a controller with `Authorize-Attribute` and gets redirected to login-page if not authenticated. On redirect the parameter `returnUrl` gets forwarded as well.

However, in case the first try of the login fails, the return to the page does not work anymore. I think the `returnUrl` gets changed to the account controller after the first try because it case the last page before the current login try. So authentication still seems to work but the user stays on the login page and doesn't get redirected to the page he was before.

Is there a way to prevent `returnUrl` from being changed after the first failed login?

Comment: Please show some code. In your implementation I think once user logged in from login page,considering it is start page requested, it is going to Accounts controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your ViewBag's returnUrl sets null after postback,

just simply put

```
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
```

at the beginning of your `HttpPost` verb of `Login` action.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start reading: I'm using entity framework code-first method here. userService is my UserDBCotext class object.  UserDbContect is context class.

Here is simple code. You can use it for LogIn action. Also for multiple login.

Controller actions:

```
public ActionResult LogIn()
        {
            return View(new ForLogIn());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(ForLogIn user)
        {
            try 
            {
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var loggedUser=userService.Users.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.UserName==user.UserName && i.UserPassword==user.UserPassword);
                    if(loggedUser!=null)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);
                        return View("LoggedIn", loggedUser);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or password is incorrect, please try again");
                        return View(user);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return View(user);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                return View(user);
            }
        }
```

LogIN view with scaffolding:

```
@model DataAccessLayer.Models.ForLogIn

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LogIn";
}

<h2>LogIn</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.UserPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassword)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Nothing special but LoggedIn view. You can just skip it and create whatever view you want:

```
@model DataAccessLayer.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoggedIn";
}

<h2>Congratulations @Model.UserName</h2>
<h3>You've Logged In successfully, please choose option below</h3>
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</p>
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Start Test", "Start", "Test")</p>
```

And finally, my user class:

```
public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter you name")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter you E-mail")]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter you Password")]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Password minimum length is 6 characters, maximum-50")]
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please repeat your password")]
        [Display(Name = "Repeate Password")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Repeated password minimum length is 6 characters, maximum-50")]
        public string UserRepeatPassword { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Is Active")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```